# How to custom Head and Proxy with wkhtmltopdf in Python?

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I use the function `pdfkit.from_url` to convert html to pdf. And I want to custom the http head and proxy. I try some code, but I fail.

My code is following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8


import pdfkit
import requests

url = 'http://www.baidu.com'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/48.0.2564.82 Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36'}
proxy ={'http': '113.119.82.69:9000'}
options = {
        'custom-header':headers,
        'proxy': proxy
        }


pdfkit.from_url(url,'out.pdf',options=options)
```

Answer (score 2):

cmd code:

```
# wkhtmltopdf -p proxy target_website output.pdf
wkhtmltopdf -p socks5://192.168.1.100:1080 https://stackoverflow.com output.pdf
```

python code:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url(
    output_path='output.pdf',
    options={
        # proxy ?
        # http://user:password@myproxyserver:8080
        # '--proxy': 'socks5://192.168.1.100:1080',
        '--proxy': 'http://113.119.82.69:9000',
        # quiet ?
        # '--quiet': ''
    },
    url='https://stackoverflow.com',
)
```